# 'Range.detach' is now a no-op, as per DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, rangy, wysihtml5

I have been noticing this warning and error message in my console after updating Chrome to 36.0.1985.125.

Warning:

```
'Range.detach' is now a no-op, as per DOM (http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-detach).
```

Error:

```
Discontiguous selection is not supported.
```

Can be seen: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/cssclassapplier.html

Other javascript/jquery plugins (wysihtml5, rangy) have also been affected, any solutions?

Comment: Remove calls to `Range.detach`. Also, that’s probably a warning, not an error.

Comment: Rangy was fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/commit/601b80c2bcc8f0c65bf233660f9e3bff5bbe9c18).

Comment: @esqew Interesting, I gave rangy an update. In his comments, looks like the error cannot be suppressed '// Next line causes Chrome 36 to print a console error of' ... (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=353069#c4)

Answer (score 5):

I'm still trying to decide what to do about this. See [this Rangy issue](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/issues/detail?id=208) (migration to GitHub not quite complete, sorry). I think it's unhelpful behaviour on the part of Chrome and [would like it removed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=399791).

The offending code in Rangy is in a feature test that determines whether the browser supports multiple ranges within a selection (of the current mainstream browsers, only Firefox does). Since this doesn't seem to be going away I think I'm going to have to suck it up and add a browser sniff, which makes me sad.

### Update

I added a horrible browser sniff to Rangy and the error no longer appears.

Comment: Could you please post code on how to fix this? I am using textAngular for a rich text editor which has the dependency on Rangy. I don't want to upgrade the version of Rangy in case it breaks. Is it something I can fix in the script?

Comment: @Asher: Upgrading Rangy shouldn't break anything because it retains backwards compatibility. However, if you want to edit Rangy yourself, you can see the fix here: https://github.com/timdown/rangy/blob/master/src/core/wrappedselection.js#L164