# Discontiguous selection is not supported Error stops Copying to Clipboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am running the following Coffescript code to copy certain data to the users clipboard.

```
ready = ->

copyEmailBtn = document.querySelector('.clipboard-copy')
copyEmailBtn.addEventListener 'click', (event) ->
  targetClass = document.querySelector('.clipboard-copy').dataset.targetClass
  target = document.querySelector(targetClass)
  range = document.createRange()
  range.selectNode target
  window.getSelection().addRange range
  try
    document.execCommand('copy')
  catch err
    console.log 'Oops, unable to copy'
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
  return

if $('.clipboard-copy').length > 0
  $(document).ready(ready)
  $(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

[When I click the related button to start the copy process chrome throws the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDAe8.png)

The issue with this is that I am not able to track it down since it only occurs in one out of 4 attempts.

The copy button works as expected those other 3 out 4 times however whenever this error occurs it doesn't copy the text.

I didn't try any other browsers since our app does not work in any other browser and is not supposed to.

Has anyone dealt with this error before?

I tried the following suggestions as you can see from the code
[Discontiguous selection is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513869/discontiguous-selection-is-not-supported)

All the other reports about this error say it shouldn't affect functionality and is more like a verbose warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with the following code

```
ready = ->

copyEmailBtn = document.querySelector('.clipboard-copy')
copyEmailBtn.addEventListener 'click', (event) ->
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
  targetClass = document.querySelector('.clipboard-copy').dataset.targetClass
  target = document.querySelector(targetClass)
  range = document.createRange()
  range.selectNode target
  window.getSelection().addRange range
  try
    document.execCommand('copy')
  catch err
    console.log 'Oops, unable to copy'
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
  return

if $('.clipboard-copy').length > 0
  $(document).ready(ready)
  $(document).on('page:load', ready)
```