# 'Range.detach' error at injecting loopback angular sdk

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sdk, loopbackjs

I have automatically created the services library with the loopback angular sdk but when I call it from my angular app it keeps in a blank page and in the javascript console I have the next error:
"'Range.detach' is now a no-op, as per DOM (http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-detach)."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020816/range-detach-is-now-a-no-op-as-per-dom).It also addresses the similar error and also discusses about the fix related to the github page.